How to backup older Gramps data before converting to the newer schema?
I have some family trees in Gramps but was away from it for a while and ended up inadvertently upgrading the software (now v5.2.3 on Linux) past the version in which I last edited the data (v3). So I want to be careful not to lose the trees as I fix this.
I think I need to:

install and launch v3
load the family trees and make backups
exit v3 and launch v5
upgrade the family trees
uninstall v5

I don't feel great about installing v3. Is there a way to install it so that it doesn't interfere with v5? Alternatively, can I uninstall v5 without losing the data?

All I needed to do was:

Back up ~/.gramps
Proceed with letting v5 try to pull in the old data.

In my case it worked immediately without apparent issues. The fact that I didn't have any media probably helped.
